# EF just edits my entity for first time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF-Rest Service as you can see :

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/EditNews", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool Edit(News entity);
```

With this code :

```
public class NewsRepository :INewsRepository
    {
        private readonly DataContext _ctx;
        public NewsRepository(DataContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;

        }

        public bool Add(News entity)
        {
            try
            {
                _ctx.News.Add(entity);
                _ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool Edit(News entity)
        {
            try
            {

                _ctx.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                _ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }
}}
```

So i call my service in my client to edit my entity as you can see :

```
 News student = new News
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("7320D87D-4819-4663-BCF9-2D09F9E4BD70"),
                Subject = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssss",
                ViewerCounter = 3, // removed the "" (string)
                MainContent = "fsdsd", // renamed from "Content"
                SubmitDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                PublisherName = "sdaadasd",
                PictureAddress = "adfafsd",
                TypeOfNews = "bbbbb"
            };
            WebClient Proxy1 = new WebClient();
            Proxy1.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializerToUplaod = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(News));
            serializerToUplaod.WriteObject(ms, student);
            byte[] a = Proxy1.UploadData("http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/EditNews", "PUT", ms.ToArray());
```

So i run my service and my client application ,and click on the edit button and my edit works.But for second time i get this error in my `Edit method`

```
Attaching an entity of type 'CMSManagement.Domain.Entity.News' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Solution

```
  public bool Edit(News entity)
            {
                try
                {
                    News Edited = _ctx.News.Where(i => i.Id == entity.Id).First();
                    _ctx.Entry(Edited).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                    _ctx.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // TODO log this error
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there aren't any other entities attached to your News model, maybe it is trying to add one entity that is attached to your news entity, just pass it without any child objects, and make sure you used `AsNoTracking()` during selecting this entity.

Comment: No .I just have an istance on news that is sent by wcf-rest

Comment: I meant is there any navigation properties attached during edit, if no, check for `AsNoTracking()` during your select on get

Comment: Could you please give me in detail how can i use AsNoTracking to avoid this error ?

Comment: before you edit the object, you call the database to get that object. 
that call, make sure it [AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) 
Last time i got this error and it turned that I forgot to add `AsNoTracking()`

Comment: It might be cached in your context, that's why, when you use asnotracking it won't be cached, so it will know it is the same item being modified